# javascript time between two dates

Tags: javascript

i have the following function:

```
function update_comments(){
    $('.comment_list_item').each(function(){
        var current_comment = $(this).find('.comment_time');
        var old_text = current_comment.text();
        var current_time = new Date().getTime();
            var timer = $(this).find('.hour_glass')
            var old_time = parseFloat(timer.val());
            var new_time = current_time - old_time;
            var minutes=1000*60;
            var hours=minutes*60;
            var days=hours*24;
        var new_text = '';
        if(days > 0){
            new_text = days+' Days ago';
        }else if(hours > 0){
            if(hours === 1){
                new_text = hours+' Hour ago';
            }else{
                new_text = hours+' Hours ago';
            }
        }else{
            if(minutes === 1){
                new_text = minutes+' Minute ago';
            }else{
                new_text = minutes+' Minutes ago';
            }
        }
        current_comment.text(new_text);
    });
}
```

Where old_time is an input field with the value `microtime(true);`

Now after 1 minute the result is 86400000 days can anyone tell me why?

Comment: You might consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you read your code carefully? It includes the following lines:

```
var minutes=1000*60;
var hours=minutes*60;
var days=hours*24;
```

So yes, you are computing minutes, hours, days based on a constant (not the difference between old time and new time). Specifically, from the above it follows that

```
days = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400000
```

just as you observed.

The following:

```
var minutes = milliseconds / (1000 * 60);
var hours = minutes / 60;
var days = hours / 24;
```

is the more conventional approach for converting milliseconds into minutes into hours into days...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `new_time` is in milliseconds (very probably), You should have:

```
var minutes = new_time / 1000 / 60;
var hours= minutes / 60;
var days = hours / 24;
```

Cheers

Comment: Thanks is there any difference between the php function microtime(true); and getTime();